# Subtract numbers using arrays - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, logic

I want to calculate the difference between two numbers (let's say `v` and `n`, so `v-n`) using arrays (don't ask why I have to do so). The arrays for each number are made in the following way:

- Their capacity is the number of digits of the greatest number between `v` and `n` (=`q` in the code)
- `vArray[i]` = `i`th digit of `v` except leading zeros to fill the whole array
- `nArray[i]` = - `i`th digit of `n` except leading zeros to fill the whole array

For example, choose `v` = 10 and `n` = 2 then,

```
vArray = [1,0]
nArray = [0,-2]
```

So I wrote this code to calculate the `sum` array that will be equal to the digits of the difference (`sum = [0,9]` for the example above):

```
long r = 0;
for (int i = q-1 ; i > -1; i--){
    sum[i] = vArray[i] + nArray[i];
    if (sum[i] < 0){
        r = floor(sum[i]/10);
        sum[i-1] -= r;
        sum[i] = sum[i]+10;
    }else{
        r = 0;
    }

    NSLog(@"%li",sum[i]);
}
```

The problem is that sum array isn't equal to what it should be. For the same example, `sum = [1,8]` What is the problem in the code?

note : `vArray` and `nArray` are properly generated.

EDIT : A few examples and expected results

```
    v =  |    n =   |  vArray =   |     nArray=    |    sum=
    25   |    9     |    [2,5]    |      [0,9]     |    [1,6]
    105  |    10    |   [1,0,5]   |     [0,1,0]    |   [0,9,5]
   1956  |   132    |  [1,9,5,6]  |    [0,1,3,2]   |  [1,8,2,4]
  369375 |   6593   |[3,6,9,3,7,5]|  [0,0,6,5,9,3] |[3,6,2,7,8,2]
```

Comment: Could it be integer division: `sum[i]/10`?  Remember, 1/2 == 0.

Comment: So what should I write instead?

Comment: I don't understand your post.  Is each array element one digit or more than one?  What does `q` represent?

Comment: "don't ask why I have to do so" - Sorry, but that's pretty much a prequesite at that point.

Comment: `q = ceil(log10(max(v,n)))` or if you prefer, the number of digit of the largest between the v and n. Each arrays contains the associated number's digits and if needed, leading zeros.

Comment: Reminds me of http://www.mikedoesweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: I know it's a stupid way to compute but I need this. Please help me.

Comment: Please edit your post to provide 2 more examples using known values and the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I understand the data structure, as you are using a *Big Integer* representation.

Given the number: 1234

Your V array is: [1, 2, 3, 4].

To add all the digits (a.k.a. sum), which I don't see why you want to do this, is:

```
int digit_sum = 0;
for (int i = 0;  i < 4; i++)
{
    digit_sum += v[i];
}
```

To convert the representation into "normal", try this:

```
int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
  value = (value * 10) + v[i];
}
```

To perform a subtraction, you will have to perform the steps as if you doing this by hand.  Also, you would need a second number too.

**Edit 1: link to big number subtraction**
This might help:
[Big Number Subtraction in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316940/big-number-subtraction-in-c)
[C++ Large Number Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430339/c-large-number-arithmetic)

Comment: Well what you are saying is true but doesn't have nothing with my code I don't to convert vArray or nArray into a integer.

Comment: Please give some examples of known numbers and the expected results.

Comment: Your link is broken man! And I'll edit the question for examples

Comment: @moray95:  Fixed links.  Search SO for "C++ big number subtraction" or "C++ big number arithmetic".